# Is deadlock possible in this case?

Tags: concurrency, process, mutex, deadlock

There are four resourses of the same type, and three processes. Each process needs 2 resourses at most. Is a deadlock possible?.
I have read some similar examples which say that once process will have 2 resourses and can run to completion, and then release those resourses, and so on. So in that way deadlock is impossible.
But my teacher insist that is a deadlock scenario, and i am not convinced with his answer.
what is the true answer?

Comment: P1 got A and waits to get B; P2 got B and waits to get C; P3 got C and waits to get A. A deadlock, no?

Comment: If you are not convinced by the teacher's answer, what data do you have to support this?

Comment: The solutions of modern operating systems . I got it from there.